# How to use a temporary container in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

This is my [image: Overall Pipeline]. It uses an array of numbers, with each number being called individually to an API in the ForEach block and I want to store them in temporary container. This is how my integration dataset is [image: setup].

In the second copy activity (outside the ForEach block), I am trying to source this data from the temporary container, merge them all together and store permanently in my data lake as [image: shown].

The problem I am facing is that it errors out at the second copy activity resulting in this error `"errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'. Account: 'XXX'. FileSystem: 'apidata'. ErrorCode: 'FilesystemNotFound'. Message: 'The specified filesystem does not exist.'. GMT'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.Models.ErrorSchemaException,Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "AppendData", "details": [] }`

Any idea on how to fix this or even access temporary containers?

Comment: Are you having required roles. Check if you have Storage blob data contributor role to Management Identity "Synapse service".
Also confirm if your main goal is to Merge the multiple csv files in to one single file?

Comment: On the synapse resource I am a contributor and on the storage account I am the storage blob data contributor.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same approach as you.
I received the below error:

[image]
I have encounterd the error when I gave folder name as **"**
[image]

However when I gave the folder name APIdata. the pipeline ran successfully.
[image]

[image]

As you mentioned you need to source data from the temporary container, merge them all together and store in ADLS
You can try **Copy Behavior MERGE Files**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: ` {
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=AdlsGen2InvalidFolderPath,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The folder path is not specified. Cannot locate the file '*.csv' under the ADLS Gen2 account directly. Please specify the folder path instead.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "AppendData",
    "details": []
} `

Got the error using your method. it cannot find the file it seems.

Comment: are you using the APIdata as folder name?

Comment: "apidata" yeah but not "APIdata".

Comment: I have added sink data set too in the solution..

Comment: Can you share the source settings screens shot

Comment: did you make a separate container named temp?

Comment: Yes created a new Conatiner temp

Comment: [so far it is this](https://imgur.com/a/6xUKJG7)

Comment: I want to access a temporary container, not a permanent instance.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of how you made your container (temp)?

Comment: in the dataset connection i have created the temp container